# Dio requests taking too long

Tags: flutter, dart, request, connection, dio

The connection time of the requests we send using dio is taking too long, how can we shorten this? I realized "connection establish" parameter take 418ms and more. How can I reduce this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg4nN.png

Answer (score 1):

you have to be more specific while making Dio calls because it will not going to load the data immediately rather it will going to examine all the data and parameters and headers you are passing with it.

You have to prepare all of it before making calls